# Importing TIFF file for use as basemap in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, basemap

I have purchased an Ordnance Survey map for use in ArcGIS Pro as a basemap. The file that I received came in a zip file and contained the a TFW File, TIFF File, OVR File and an XML Document. When I open the TIFF file normally in Windows, it is a high resolution file (73 mb). However, when I "Add data" in ArcGIS Pro and import the TIFF file, it is very blurry as a base map and is not high resolution.

Are there any special tips to follow when importing a TIFF file for use as a basemap in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Two things to try investigating: 1. Coordinate conversion: does the map use the same coordinate system as the TIF? 2. Is it still blurred if you zoom to source resolution? If not, then there might be a problem with the creation of pyramids.

Comment: The `.ovr` file is an image pyramid (overview) file that downsamples the large image for fast rendering.  You can remove the pyramid or rebuild it with more appropriate parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the coordinate system is for the map is that same as that as the TIF. When I select "zoom to source resolution", the TIF is not blurred and is fairly high resolution. Any further suggestions based on this info would be much appreciated.